# Google Plus website not linking

Tags: seo, google, google-plus

I'm getting below error when trying to link Google Plus page with my site:

```
Check that the line of code was added to your site's homepage and that the modified homepage is live on your site. Then try testing again.
```

I have got correct link set up like below (obviously {pageId} is replaced) but I'm still getting this error. I have got this link across all pages in the sidebar.

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/{pageId}" rel="publisher">Google+</a>
```

I got this working on other sites but somehow this site is not linking. Is there a reason why? Other sites also have the Google Plus link on sidebar of every page

Comment: Without a link to your site, it isn't possible for me to look myself and see if there are any problems.  From the markup that you have pasted here, it looks fine.  Put a link to your site in, and we can help better.  Here is the help page from Google on the topic: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1708844

Comment: @StephenOstermiller my website is hirenerds.com.au

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong.  You do have several rel="publisher" link tags on the page, only one of which is in the <head> section.  They all appear to have the same google plus link.  The only thing I can think is that multiple tags is somehow confusing the situation.

Comment: It wasn't working before the google plus meta tag. I have already tried without it but it still doesn't work...I'm out of options now...

Answer (score 1):

Google's Structured Data only works when one Author is present on the page, on the front page online you have 6 authors and 3 publishers all duplicates.